# Restoring postgreSQL backup to MySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, phpmyadmin

How to restore postgreSQL backup file to MySQL server? I don't have postgreSQL server on my system. I have only MySQL server

Comment: super users might be a better place for this type of question.

Comment: Please change the title of the question to reflect what is needed.

Comment: @wheaties: +1 I agree, or serverfault.

Comment: 'Super Users' meaning this website: http://superuser.com/

Comment: Terrible question....please re-edit and be consistent in your formatting...

Answer (score 6):

Install PostgreSQL, restore from backup, export the schema and data then import into MySQL.